# how to load dynamic html string in webview

Tags: react-native

I want to load dynamic html string in webview when the asynchronously web service request is finished. How can I do this?

```
 <WebView source={{html: dynamichtml}}/>

 getMoviesFromApiAsync()
 {
   return fetch('*****some url*****')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     this.setState({isLoading: false, jsonData: responseJson});
     this.getDataFromServer(responseJson);
     return responseJson;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
```

}

```
 getDataFromServer(responseJson)
 {
   var a ='ravi';
   var b = 'chennai';
   var commonHtml = `my name is ${a} from ${b}`;
   <WebView source={{html: commonHtml}}/>  // not working
 }
```

Comment: hi, any advance?

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish that by e.g. delaying the rendering of `WebView` until the request has finished:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    commonHtml = ''
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  getMoviesFromApiAsync();
}

getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
  fetch('*****some url*****')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    // Assuming responseJson.data.nameA and responseJson.data.nameB exist
    const { nameA, nameB } = responseJson.data;
    this.setState({commonHtml: `my name is ${nameA} from ${nameB}`});
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

render() {
  const commonHtml = { this.state };

  return (
    <View>
      {commonHtml ?
        <WebView style={{width: 200, height: 200}} source={{html: commonHtml}} /> :
        (
          <View>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

This example renders `WebView` only when there is some content in `this.state.commonHtml`.

In fact, the ternary isn't even needed if you don't want to do anything fancy. You can simply do

```
render() {
  return (
    <WebView style={{width: 200, height: 200}} source={{html: this.state.commonHtml}} />
  );
}
```

and `setState` causes a re-render when `this.state.commonHtml` changes.